# How do you model a path parameter in the middle with http4k

Tags: kotlin, http4k

I am using http4k-contracts and I am trying to model a route with a path parameter in the middle of the path, i.e.

This is the path: `/player/{id}/match`

This is my code (does not compile): `"/player/" / Path.string().of("id") / "match" meta { ..`

Whats the right way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this doesn't compile, it probably means that the function on the end of that statement doesn't have enough parameters. You need something like this - notice the "dead" parameter in the middle of the lambda where the string "foo" would be injected:

```kotlin
"/prefix" / Path.of("first") / "foo" / Path.of("second") 
    bindContract GET to { first, _, second -> { 
        Response(OK).body("$first $second") }
    }
```

Trailing parameters work in exactly the same way, so by extrapolation you'd need this:

```
val route = "/prefix" / Path.of("first") / "foo" meta { description = "I am great"} bindContract GET to { first, _ -> { Response(OK).body(first) } }
```

For adding the meta tags, you can easily get tripped up by the infix whitespace, so try playing with the line breaks if it doesn't compile.

Comment: Your example doesnt have a fixed String at the end of the path.

Comment: Well spotted, however the question is titled "How do you model a path parameter in the middle with http4k". I'll edit the above to add that. :)

Comment: Thanks, David. In my non working example, I had `Path.string().of("id")` instead of `Path.of("first")`. I also used `meta` straight after the path instead of having `bindContract` directly. Either one of them makes it not compile then I guess. How would you specify the `meta` in your second example?

Comment: see above  ^^ :)

Comment: Okay I fully understand the issue now, thanks! So basically there is no way to exclude the "dead' parts in the path? These always have to be added as arguments to the function or, in your example, ignored using `_`?

Comment: That's right - the problem is that the parsing of the "part" (ie. making sure it's exactly the matching string) is independent of the declaration - so as far as the routing is concerned there are still the same number of parts.